# How to run the java command programmatically in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, we can run some of the command line tools programmatically using a class called `ToolProvider`.

For example, if I wanted to run the command line tool `jpackage`, I would call the respective [`ToolProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.jpackage/module-summary.html) that is respective to the `jdk.jpackage` module.

Same goes for `jlink`, or the `jar` command.

Is there anyway for me to do something like that for the `java` command? And if not, how do I call the `java` command programmatically?

Finally, I am aware of the `java.lang.Process` version of doing this. If there truly is no other way, then I will accept that answer.

Comment: @Sweeper Is this a duplicate? The OP seems to be explicitly looking for an in-process solution.

Comment: @Slaw I know, but I'm pretty sure there is no such thing. Different JVMs has to be different processes as far as I know. The post also said "If there truly is no other way, then I will accept that answer", so I closed it.

Comment: Note tools like `jar`, `jlink`, and `jpackage` are all relatively simple. They are written in Java and can thus be directly executed by any Java application without starting a new JVM. In contrast, the `java` tool's primary purpose is to start a new JVM. Like Sweeper, as far as I know you cannot run two or more JVMs in the same process. In other words, invoking the `java` tool inherently involves creating a new process. Given that can already be accomplished via `ProcessBuilder`, there is not much incentive to provide a `ToolProvider` implementation or similar API for the `java` tool.

Comment: @Slaw Ty for the rundown. I figured it would be the case, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Sweeper Based on what you and Slaw say, it definitely seems like this is the only option. No real loss, I wasn't missing out on much, it seems.

Comment: afaics `java` is not in any of the tools modules

Comment: @g00se Thanks for looking into it. I was starting to suspect so, but I could not confirm.

Comment: Having said that, I'm trying to think of a scenario where you'd want to invoke `java` from inside a Java app and I must say I can't think of one...

Comment: @g00se I am helping out with development of an IDE. The IDE itself runs on Java, but not necessarily the same Java version as the application that the user is running in the IDE.

Comment: For both versions to be fully independent you would *have* to create a separate process. So...`ProcessBuilder` is what you want